# How to choose all possible sub-arrays from an array

Tags: c++

I want to use the [Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to find out the no. of numbers in a range not divisible by the no.s in an array. To do this we need to choose all possible sub-arrays (or to use the mathematical term subsets). One way to do this is take a binary number of length n (the length of the array) and increment it in every iteration. Now the places in which we have 1's are taken and the rest are rejected. This way we can ensure we choose all possible sub-arrays of the array. I am not sure how to implement this. Please help.

Comment: I want to copy paste my assignment instructuons into a stack overflow question and have someone else do my homework without showing any evidence of effort.  I am not sure how to implememt this.  Please help.

Comment: @Yakk it is not a homework assignment. The question link is http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/LEAFEAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A range of numbers (subarray) can be represented by a structure:

```
struct Range1
{
  int begin_value;
  int end_value;
};

struct Range2
{
  int begin_value;
  unsigned int range_length;
};
```

Now all you need is an array of ranges and code to use the array of ranges.

Comment: the no.s are not necessarily continuous. So we cant describe them with the beginning and ending value. Please see this link http://snag.gy/3nigH.jpg

Comment: So, what is the range when both begin and end values are the same?  Did you see the other structure?

Comment: i dont really understand what you are trying to say... but the paste in the link describes what i want...

Comment: A range of 1 value can be represented in Range1 by having the begin and end values equal.  In Range2, a range of 1 value can be represented by having the begin_value represent the value and the range_length is 1.

Comment: so u mean begin_value and end_value are array indices... ok , but how do i et the values to ensure all sub arrays are taken?

Comment: know i mean begin_value and end_value are values.  For example, to describe the range 50 to 65, begin_value == 50 and end_value == 65.  Et'in the values are a challenge for you.